# Java to Swift conversion - How to increment the index count in Swift

Tags: java, swift

This seems so simple but I'm stuck. I'm getting the usual Index Out Of Bounds Swift errors. It seems Java can set the amount of indexes an array has from the start and increment the total number of indexes as well.

I know what the issue is but I don't know the Swift equivalent of this Java function.  The Java function has a post incrementor for increasing the index count of the EMPTY array. I don't know how to write that in Swift. With Swift you have to use append. You can not use subscripting on an empty array. PLUS I don't know how to increase the index count.

How do I convert this Java to Swift?

Java

```
private int[] theArray;
private int itemsInArray = 0;

public void addItemToArray(int newItem) {
        theArray[itemsInArray++] = newItem;
    }
```

Swift

```
var theArray = [Int]()
var itemsInArray = 0

func addItemArray(newItem: Int) {
    theArray[itemsInArray] += newItem
}
addItemArray(newItem: 5)
```

Comment: *But with Swift you have to use append* – Doesn't that already answer your question?

Comment: Is there any reason to be using `itemsInArray`?  You could just use `theArray.append(newItem)` and then simply use `theArray.count` to get the number of available elements. A Swift Array is more like a `List` then a Java array

Comment: *"Java can set the amount of indexes an array has from the start and increment the total number of indexes as well"* - Not sure that makes sense.  A Java array is fixed length, what the code is doing is moving the index to the next location and then applying the value to that element, but since it's not guarding against the fact that `itemsInArray` could be higher then the available elements (ie `length`) it could generate a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as well...and the Swift code isn't even close to doing the same thing

Comment: @TokyoToo I added a bit of explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per documentation, to initialize an `Array` with a default size use

```
var theArray = Array(repeating: "", count: itemsInArray) // Where repeating is the contained type
```

You can then `insert` via

```
theArray.insert(newItem, at: yourIndex)
```

`Array`(s) in Java must have an initial `size`, which cannot be changed after creation. However Swift has types comparable to Java `Collection<T>` types, which can have variable `size`.

For example

```
private int[] theArray;
```

will compile, but it will also produce a `NullPointerException` on the first access, since it isn't properly initialized

```
private int[] theArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
private int[] theArray = new int[10];
```

You would also need to be careful, both in Java and Swing, to access the correct index range, using the `myArray[index]` notation in Java, or the `myArray.insert(item, at: index)` notation in Swing.

---

The Java line `theArray[itemsInArray++] = newItem` of your example means

1. assign the `newItem` value to the `itemsInArray` index
2. increment `itemsInArray` (see *post-increment* operator)

In Swift you can just append a new element to the `Array`, you don't even need to maintain an index like `itemsInArray`

```
var theArray = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
theArray.append("Four")

var theIntegerArray = [1, 2, 3]
theIntegerArray.append(4)
```

Or with an empty array

```
var theIntegerArray: Array<Int> = []
theIntegerArray.append(4)
```

Yes, you can use `repeating` with `Integer` values.
Just

```
Array(repeating: 0, count: itemsInArray)
```

Comment: @TokyoToo see updated answer. Just ask if you need clarifications

Comment: @TokyoToo then the first four lines of my answer will suffice. Just create a new Array with a default initial size, and use insert. This would be the most similar version to Java

Comment: @TokyoToo yes, here you're starting from an empty array, but you're not maintaining an index. This is the same example I used in my answer, and it's not comparable to the Java one.

Comment: @TokyoToo see the "Or with an empty array" part.